# How to perform file operation on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and looking for a solution or an approach. 
I have a spring boot app and I want to deploy it on AWS, but the heart of the app is mostly standard file operations.  ex: File file = new File("Path to file").
These files will be read and updated very frequently. How to achieve that on AWS? Is that even possible?

Any approach or some idea will be very helpful.

Comment: When you say "on AWS", to which service are you referring? Where will your app be running (eg on an Amazon EC2 instance)? How do you intend to use Amazon S3? Please edit your question to provide more details about your application architecture. Or, if you don't know the architecture, please let us know what you're trying to achieve. Please note that StackOverflow is for programming Q&A questions, so you might actually get a better response to architectural questions at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't aware of EC2, i was looking at the Elastic Beanstalk and that doesn't seem to be the right fit.

Comment: Amazon EC2 are virtual machines. Elastic Beanstalk runs atop EC2 instances. Then there are AWS Lambda functions, which are serverless and typically run for just a few seconds in response to events. Or there are Containers (Amazon ECS, Amazon Fargate, Kubernetes). Or, you can run the code on your own computer and call AWS services via API calls. Lots of options! Thus, it's typically easiest to start with a high-level architecture and then figure out which services to use.